# Grails development enviornment page loads very slow

Tags: grails

So I'm getting page load times in the range of 30-45 seconds.

Some history:

This was not always the case for this project. This project is in production so I haven't really touched the code in a while. I noticed it started happening the last time I was updating the code. I don't recall anything specific that I changed that should have anything to do with the problem. I have other projects that are running with the same Grails versions with no problem.

I think it started happening in 2.2.3. I am now running 2.2.4.

I am using x64 JDK 1.7.0_25, Windows 7 x64.

I'm not sure what else to put here that would be relevant. Any assistance is appreciated!

**Edit**: running with -noreloading has no effect.

**Edit2**: I've tried deleting my `.grails` folder entirely, running `clean`, and deleting my target folder and stacktrace log.

**Edit3**: It does seem that the amount of time it takes is dependent on the amount of data displayed/read. Small pages take 3-4 seconds. Medium pages 10-12 seconds...

**Edit4**: I'm running it via IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4 x64 (idea64.exe). I've also tried it outside of IntelliJ with the same results.

**Edit5**: The database is Oracle enterprise that supports the entire company. It is managed by full time adminstrators. This isn't a MySQL server on my local machine.

**Edit6**: The application also functions normally when deployed in TEST (`test war`), but still is slow when ran with `test run-app`.

**Starting to get somewhere**:
I downloaded JDK 1.7.21 and ran the app with that and it started working no problem! I then ran `clean` which triggered a recompile and it stopped working... grr

Now with 1.7.21 still active, I tried `-noreloading` and it works!

Annnd... now it works even if I don't use `-noreloading`..........

I've gone back to 1.7.25.. ran `clean`, and it works. Sooooooo yeah... explain that.

And now it doesn't anymore.

Comment: Is there any database interactions while the page is loading?

Comment: Yes there is - quite a lot. However it used to load in ~2-3 seconds.

Comment: Might be a RAM problem! Can you have a look on your logs ?

Comment: Another question: Your headline says it happens in development env, but your question says it happens in production. What's right ?

Comment: I can run another project simultaneously that load the page in normal times

Comment: The project has been put into production. The point of saying that was that there is no problem with the project in production. It runs fine there.

Comment: Try benchmarking with same database maybe be problem lies in db, another suggestion try some sort of profiler. VisualVM is good to start.

Comment: Is it within an IDE ? if so check my post below

Comment: have you checked your data base? is everything fine with it? is it remote?

Comment: i would increase the logs and check what makes him busy

Comment: I installed VisualVM - I'm not sure what this data could tell me. What should I look for?

Comment: Edit 3 seems to give you a clue. Enable logSql and analyze your queries. Maybe your dev database are with some index missing or you need to update the statistics...

Comment: The dev database gets cloned from production every week. It's exactly the same. The key here is that the project runs perfectly when deployed. THIS ONLY HAPPENS IN DEV MODE. If it were a problem with my queries - it would show up everywhere.

Comment: Look for memory spikes or any abnormal cpu,gc activity, heap etc. but based on your updates, it seems more related to environmental factors. delete your local temp directory, and also using firebug or something make sure the delay is not for loading css,js stuff.

Comment: What temp dir are you referring to?

Comment: The resources plugin writes the processed files in a tmp directory, if you have not configured `grails.resources.work.dir` it, might be where ever your servlet container has it defined or your system temp not sure. On unix, we had a problem similar like yours it turned out to be some files being locked or something that led to slow loading. It might help cleaning them.

Comment: @JamesKleeh sometimes problems with queries are related to the environment. I've seen this kind of problem when the dev database are not updated, but this is not your case.

Comment: Have you checked your css, js load times with firebug or yslow? With VisualVM you can look the cpu use, this will tell you witch method have the highest spent time. I had a custom code that called the i18n messages more than I needed, this only affected the dev env since the reload happens only here. One more test: have you tried without the reload agent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the reason why this was happening:

**JDK 1.7.25**

Comment: was JDK 1.7.25 the problem, or the solution?

Comment: Yknow I can't really say. At the time I thought it was the problem, but it was so erratic.

Answer (score 1):

This is under Linux but will maybe useful:

If you are running the code within an IDE:

ps auwx|grep java

-Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6 **-Xms40m -Xmx768m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -**

As you can see the memory settings Xms and Xmx are quite low...

In your IDE there should be an INI file:

```
more STS.ini 
      1 -vm
      2 /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
      3 -startup
      4 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
      5 --launcher.library
      6 plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20120913-144807
      7 -product
      8 org.springsource.sts.ide
      9 --launcher.defaultAction
     10 openFile
     11 -vmargs
     12 -Dgrails.console.enable.interactive=false
     13 -Dgrails.console.enable.terminal=false
     14 -Djline.terminal=jline.UnsupportedTerminal
     15 -Dgrails.console.class=grails.build.logging.GrailsEclipseConsole
     16 -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.6
     17 -Xms40m
     18 -Xmx768m
     19 -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
```

You can up these value and try restarting your IDE...

I would also suggest you run something like nmon before/during and monitor whilst the code is running and monitor disk/cpu/network throughputs.

You may find you are hammering your dev box which is causing the issue.

If the production is fine I really don't see what the problem is..

E2A Ahhh forgot it was under windows so no nmon for windblows but hey not that I tried it - http://sourceforge.net/projects/jnmonanalyser/

E2A again:
1. Enable DataSource.groovy debugging:

```
dataSource {
    pooled = true
    driverClassName ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    username = "aaa"
    password = "aaaa"
    //SQL Logging - refer to Config.groovy at hibernate.sql now
    logSql=true
    ...
```

1. config.groovy - this will stop your app from running if you have issues with lets say records you are trying to add in your BootStrap

   // Return error when it fails
   //grails.gorm.failOnError=true

Enable log4j and use this or part of it:

```
// log4j configuration
log4j {
    appender.stdout = "org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender"
    appender.'stdout.layout'="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
    appender.'stdout.layout.ConversionPattern'='[%r] %c{2} %m%n'
    appender.stacktraceLog = "org.apache.log4j.FileAppender"
    appender.'stacktraceLog.layout'="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout"
    appender.'stacktraceLog.layout.ConversionPattern'='[%r] %c{2} %m%n'
    appender.'stacktraceLog.File'="stacktrace.log"
    appender.'stacktraceLog.MaxFileSize'="1MB"
    rootLogger="error,stdout"
    logger {
        grails="error"
        StackTrace="error,stacktraceLog"
        org {
            codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet="error"  //  controllers
            codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages="error" //  GSP
            codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh="error" //  layouts
            codehaus.groovy.grails."web.mapping.filter"="error" // URL mapping
            codehaus.groovy.grails."web.mapping"="error" // URL mapping
            codehaus.groovy.grails.commons="info" // core / classloading
            codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins="error" // plugins
            codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate="error" // hibernate integration

            // Hibernate should be on - if you want to catch sql logs
            springframework="off"
            hibernate="on"
            //hibernate.SQL = 'debug'
            //hibernate.type = 'trace'
            //hibernate.SQL = 'info,hibernate'
            //hibernate.type = 'info,hibernate'
            //hibernate = 'info,hibernate'


            //apache.commons.digester.Digester = 'debug,javaclasses'
        }
    }
    additivity.StackTrace=false
}
```

try and capture what it is doing, it is also worth running developer tools on your browser whether its firefox of chrome and trying to figure out on what elements it is taking that time - but between the logs and the browser developer tools should lie your answer.

Comment: I tried these settings - no dice. I am currently running other Grails apps using the same setup with NO problems.

Comment: Try creating new workspace same project name then copy from existing project the grails-app and Web apps folder across to it. Refresh new project. Try it trom new work space. See if makes. Any diff

Comment: Just tried it - same things happening. It must be a setting or something I have in this project. I just can't figure it out.

Comment: Final test that comes to mind is to run tomcat locally  put war in local ttomcat stop ide. Start tomcat goto 8080 address see if lag goes

Answer (score 0):

Usually you can fix this by doing

```
grails clean
```

on the grails command line (I open it via CRTL+ALT+G in IntelliJ IDEA).
This erases all compiled files and will recompile your project from scratch (afaik), which usually erases errors like that. This is not a real fix for the underlying problem, but it solves the problem. Grails is highly experimental and unstable if you ask me, i have a lot of weird error that usually disappear when doing a `clean`. Btw i'm using 2.1.5 on Windows 7 x64, too.

Comment: Netflix, Skydrive, eHarmony and else are using "Grails which is highly experimental and unstable"??? :-)

Comment: @dmahapatro I'm working in one of the most successful internet companies in Europe, and yes we use Grails. But i really think, after having seen this in action for 3+ years, that grails is not stable and not established. It's okay to work with, I really dont want to diss Grails, but there happens too much unforeseen stuff, so i would really say that it's in some kind of "experimental" state.

Comment: @Panique I don't think that your problem is the same as the OP. Maybe it's a good case to try to reproduce your issue, or discuss it on the mail list. I don't think that "experimental" or "unstable" are the right words for your case. It can be something related with  the agent reloader. Anyway, short reply: help Grails be better!

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete stacktrace file in the target folder of your project. It can
   get huge. (At present mine is 48 GB).
2. Check if there is enough space in your C directory.
3. If you are hot swapping code, then page loads can get slow. So in such cases, restart the dev server (grails app).
4. Sometimes, requests to the server can hang, where focusing (left or right clicking on the cmd) on the command prompt seems to skip the pause. (weird)
5. Increasing the JVM permgen, heap spaces depending on your memory might help as well.
6. Try running the server using command prompt rather within an IDE.
7. Better use methods for actions than closures.

For a system with 3GB RAM, my environment variable setting is:

```
JAVA_OPTS
-Xms512m -Xmx1g
```

The STS.ini settings:

```
-startup
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.2.0.v20110502.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.100.v20110502
-product
com.springsource.sts.ide
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
384M
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Xmn128m
-Xms1024m
-Xmx1024m
-Xss2m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=512m
-XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=10
-XX:MaxHeapFreeRatio=50
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:+CMSIncrementalMode
-XX:+CMSIncrementalPacing
-XX:+UserParallelGC
```

8) Maybe the problem is with the JDK and grails versions combination. There seems to be an error with [OpenJDK 1.7u25 and spring loaded](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10312). Okay, you are not using OpenJDK, but try with other version anyway. Try with `JDK1.7u03`.
9) Try JVM with -server flag, and see if it improves runtime performance.

```
grails run-app -server
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but unfortunately none of this is the problem. 1. Done before 2. Its not a problem 3. I'm not 4. Not sure what you mean 5. Memory isnt a problem 6. I did 7. I am

Comment: Did you try different versions of JDK? Are you using the same JDK version used in production?